# Pandas: use whole string as separator on CSV file

Tags: python, regex, pandas

In my CSV file each row is separated with delimiter `"$$$Field$$$"` (simple string, is not a regex). I am trying to do the following, but it is ignoring the separator.

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep='\b$$$Field$$$\b')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is ignoring the separator, so it automatically determines this (and picks the wrong one, a tab)

Comment: `sep=\b$$$Field$$$\b` it's not valid python code.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you need escape `$` by `\`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""Food$$$Field$$$Taste
Apple$$$Field$$$a
Banana$$$Field$$$b"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep='\$\$\$Field\$\$\$',engine='python')
print (df)
     Food Taste
0   Apple     a
1  Banana     b
```

[`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) docs:

> sep
>
> : str, defaults to ',' for read_csv(), \t for read_table()
>
> Delimiter to use. If sep is None, will try to automatically determine this. **Separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+' will be interpreted as regular expressions**, will force use of the python parsing engine and will ignore quotes in the data. Regex example: '\r\t'.